# PERMISSION_DENIED: Insufficient project quota to satisfy request: resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am following a tutorial using an account with $300 credits so I am limited to what I can do generally but I would want to know what the contents of this error I get when trying to resize a node-pool or add another node-pool to my gcp project, here is the error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.resize) PERMISSION_DENIED: Insufficient project quota to satisfy request: resource "CPUS_ALL_REGIONS": request requires '9.0' and is short '3.0'. project has a quota of '12.0' with '6.0' available.

And for the creation command this is the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.container.node-pools.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=
>           (1) insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "CPUS": request requires '3.0' and is short '1.0'. project has a quota of '8.0' with '2.0' available.

The parts that interest me are:

- insufficient project quota
- request requires '9.0' and is short '3.0', and
- project has a quota of '12.0' with '6.0' available

And the commands I am using are:

> gcloud container clusters resize my-reginal-cluster --region us-central1 --node-pool default-pool --size 4

and

> gcloud container node-pools create my-pool --num-nodes=1 --cluster my-reginal-cluster --region us-central1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first error i would suggest you to follow this [Quota Increase documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746?hl=en#) to request an increase in the quota. Otherwise delete unused resources or deploy a setup with less CPU requirements.

For the second error, insufficient regional quota meas that the region it's running short on resources. You must deploy a setup with less resources or in another region.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for now I will have to reduce my resources as this is a learning account for me

Comment: @ChristianGonzales both of these are quota limit errors, not resource capacity constraints in the second case. One refers to a global quota, the other refers to a regional one.

Answer (score 5):

By default create cluster command tries to spin up 9 nodes (3 nodes in 3 availability zones)  for the availability regions. You can limit the number of nodes by adding --num-nodes parameter in create cluster command.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer from user2047665 is correct. I tried with --num-nodes=1. CPU error resolved. But new issue came wrt DISK.

```
ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0' and is short '80.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '220.0' available
```

So I have also added --disk-size

```
gcloud container clusters create --machine-type=e2-medium --region=us-central1 --num-nodes=1 --disk-size=10 lab-cluster
```

It works